# How should I set my WebSecurityConfig antMatcher to permit all frontend Router URL if I want to serve static React build files through Spring Boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I export my React build folder to the SpringBoot resources folder and want to serve them statically. I set the antMatcher for my backend endpoints to permit some of urls access,
and rest of urls which are not permitted would need some authentication.

```
 http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/registration","/api/v1/login")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and()
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

The current situation is that, my frontend React Router URL is also blocked by the antMatcher.

e.g.
[http://localhost:8080/login being blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWNT1.png)

I can solve it by just manully hard coding the frontend url into antMatchers, like

```
.antMatchers("/api/v1/registration","/api/v1/login", "/login","/registration"...)
                .permitAll()
```

but I wonder if there is any elegant way to tell backend not to block frontend url? If the website is growing big, adding URL into antMatcher would be time-consuming.

Comment: Listing out all the endpoints that don't require authentication is the recommended approach. The code you have shared is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we have some basic principles to think about:

- Your web server could have some files that should be open to all (such as `robots.txt` and `favicon.ico`), on top of the static frontend (which may or may not need to be public without respect to this).
- When configuring security, it's better to have a baseline which is to deny all requests and then instead whitelist the requests you want to let through, as opposed to permit all except for a few which you deny. It is easier to forget about paths this way and accidentally allow access to things that should be restricted.
- Typically with an open static frontend, the sensitive content is provided from api endpoints which serve the dynamic content (this is NOT the case with a dynamic frontend rendered on the server of course).

An approach that I like is to use multiple ordered configurations for different groups. As far as I know, this can't be accomplished so easily with one configuration, and since complexity is also an enemy of security, this is an approach I like:

```kotlin
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Order(1)
class OpenConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/*", "/locales", "/avatars", "robots.txt")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll()
    }

}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
class RestrictedConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                // more fine-grained control within matched group of requests here
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()

    }
}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(3)
class CatchAllConfig: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .denyAll()
    }

}
```

With `.requestMatchers()` you determine which requests you want to process in this config and after `.authorizeRequests()`, you can determine more in details what you want to do with the matched requests. If `.requestMatchers()` (or a similar method) is omitted, all requests are matched by the configuration. The configurations are looked up in order and the first that matches the request in question is used.

You CAN do something similar to the above with one configuration but I think both that it's easier to think about it structurally when dividing it into multiple configurations and also Spring security seems to behave more consistently (once you involve authentication methods, your choices after `.authorizeRequests()` can sometimes not have the intended results if you try to control paths in widely different ways).

If you want to do it in the most secure way, then you should explicitly whitelist every static asset that you want public access to, but given that you rebuild the frontend every now and then with new hashes attached to filenames, this becomes tedious. The above is a middle way where you assume that all content that is one level under `/` belongs to the static frontend and should thus be available without authentication (you could work with file suffixes here as a complement if you want). Any folders under the static frontend must be specifically specified. All you have to do now is make sure that any dynamic content is placed in some path which is secured and that you don't have any packages which automatically adds paths to your application which you don't want to be open and that are added at the root (typically Swagger UI and actuators can do this even though the latter often put them under the `/actuator/` path.

Comment: The "Order" concept is super super helpful, thank you so much!!!